# Ruby 2.3.4 -- How to delete a substring of a string?

Tags: ruby, range, substring

For example: there has a string:

```
'Trump is great#Trump is great#'
```

If I do:

```
'Trump is great#Trump is great#'.delete! 'Trump is great#'
```

I will get:

```
''
```

But I want to get:

```
'Trump is great#'
```

So I want to a range of `'Trump is great#'`, and delete this substring by this range.

How to do that?

Or other ways to delete a substring?

Comment: Is _Trump is great_ just an example? Is the pattern you want to sanitize always the same - a sting with a `#` and the prefix and the suffix is the same string (_text#text_)?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is `sub!`.
Unlike `gsub!` or `delete!`, it only replaces the first match.

```
'Trump is great#Trump is great#'.sub!('Trump is great#', '')
=> 'Trump is great#'
```

Since it accepts regular expressions, you could use `gsub` to define how many times you would like for it to match.

Answer (score 3):

If your string is always doubled...

```
str.gsub!(/^(.*)(?=\1$)/, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

I find I can do this! :

```
'Trump is great#Trump is great#'.slice! 'Trump is great#'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of your string is similar, you can do something like:

```
string.split('#').first + '#'
```

You can also add a custom method to string Class:

```
class String
  def cut_pound
    split('#').first + '#'
  end
end
```

So, in case you are having strings with same pattern:

```
string1 = 'Wimbledon Open#Wimbledon Open#'
string2 = 'FIFA world cup#FIFA world cup#'
```

Is it possible to call:

```
string1.cut_pound # => "Wimbledon Open#"
string2.cut_pound # => "FIFA world cup#"
```

You can remove the pound getting rid of  `+ '#'`